# Proving that $(xy)!/y!^x$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

I'm learning about factorials and combinatorics in class, and this problem came up, but I don't know how to solve it. The teacher said that it would be an integer, but how can I show this?
$$
\frac{\left ( mk \right )!}{k!^{m}} \in  \mathbb{N}
$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's even true that $\frac{(mk)!}{k!^{m}m!}$ is an integer, but the proof of that which I know uses group theory, which I'm guessing you have not done yet.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I encountered this problem a while back; that counts the number of ways of partitioning a set of size $mk$ into subsets of size $k$, so that's a combinatorial proof. For an algebraic proof that uses only the fact that binomial coefficients are integers (I had a professor harp on this as a virtue for whatever reason, and I can't get myself out of that mindset), observe that $$\frac{(mk)!}{k!^m m!} = \binom{mk-1}{k-1} \binom{(m-1)k-1}{k-1} \cdots \binom{2k-1}{k-1} \binom{k-1}{k-1}.$$ If you don't mind me asking, I am curious what your group-theoretic proof is?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: The group theoretic proof uses Lagrange's theorem ( the order of  subgroup divides the order of the group). The symmetric group $S_{mk}$ (of order $(mk)!$) has a subgroup denoted $S_{k} \wr S_{m},$ which has order $(k!)^{m}m!$. The latter group is semidirect product of the form $BP,$ where $B$ is a direct product of $m$ copies of $S_{k}$ and $P$ is isomorphic to $S_{m}$ which permutes the $m$ direct factors of $B$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceed by induction on $m$. Clearly, if $m=1$ you have $\frac{k!}{k!} = 1$ is an integer.
Now, for the inductive step consider
$$\frac{((m+1)k)!}{(k!)^{m+1}} = \frac{(mk)!}{(k!)^m} \frac{(mk+1)(mk+2) \cdots (mk+k)}{k!}$$

By hypothesis $\frac{(mk)!}{(k!)^m}$ is an integer, so if you prove that
$$\frac{(mk+1)(mk+2) \cdots (mk+k)}{k!} $$
is an integer you are done.

But this is true because the product of $k$ consecutive numbers is divisible by $k!$.

Comment: ...and also equals to ${k(m+1) \choose k}$.

Answer (score 5):

You have a total of $xy$ balls, namely $y$ balls of each of $x$ colors. In how many ways can you arrange these balls in a line, when two arrangements that cannot be distinguished colorwise are considered  equal?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{(mk)!}{k!^m}=\frac{\color{red}{(1.2\cdots k)}\color{green}{((k+1).(k+2)\cdots(2k))}\cdots\color{blue}{(((m-1)k+1).((m-1)k+2)\cdots(mk))}}{\color{red}{k!}.\color{green}{k!}\cdots\color{blue}{k!}}$$
Does that gave you some **HINT**?

Comment: I tried that approach at first... didn't realize how much more simple it looks with colours though!